# Do I want a container handling multiple requests?

Tags: php, hosting, docker

This question does not pertain to networking or hosting, but to how I architect my application: If I'm setting up a docker container to be a PHP web node, is the proper convention that I set it up such that it can handle multiple connections?

Alternatively, would it be better to set it up such that it handles requests one at a time, and then if I want to handle more connections concurrently, spin up multiple instances of the same image?

Comment: Makes no sense why this has so many down votes.  Only thing I can think of is that you have really angered some group in the past.

Comment: I'm not going to link to it from here, but this question ended up getting hurt by the Stack Overflow "meta effect" and was very nearly closed (I had to fight to keep it open).  That said, I think this question comes up often and getting the right wording for it is difficult.  Hopefully over time, the misinformed downvotes will be offset by this question's merit.

Comment: [The meta effect goes both ways.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276642/1068283) :)

Comment: Indeed. Unfortunately it can also be about what was said first. Something positive or something negative. Thanks for the awesome note. I up voted :)

Comment: Well, I said I would answer the question, so I did, now that it's reopened. I think I hit all of the issues that you raised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Docker container is generally meant to run a single (logical) application and limit the resources that that application uses (memory, disk I/O, network bandwidth, etc.). This doesn't necessarily mean running a single process; it may have ancillary things such as a process monitor, but in general a PHP container is only going to run the PHP interpreter. And that will run multiple copies of itself.

As we know, nginx and php-fpm are both perfectly capable of handing multiple simultaneous requests, up to the available resource limits. Thus a single container can serve multiple requests. So can Apache with mod_php, though in this case PHP is embedded in Apache and limits what Apache can handle. So you may well want to separate the web server and PHP into separate (linked) containers anyway.

So what will happen is that you eventually get enough traffic that a single container can't handle it all fast enough, or at all. At that point you will either want to enlarge the container or fire up a new one. Generally, nginx can handle thousands of simultaneous requests and PHP can handle dozens (these are ballpark figures). So at scale you may have 800 PHP containers served by four nginx containers, with two haproxy load balancer containers in front of them, all processing from 10,000 to a peak 40,000 requests a second.

All of those 800 PHP containers won't necessarily be on 800 hosts, though. This could be the case if you are using, say, t2.small AWS instances, where you would just have the container use all the resources of the VM, but if IT deploys to bare metal, which usually has much more resources than a single VM, you almost certainly will have multiple containers on that host, so as to utilize all of its resources. PHP tends to be CPU-bound, so IT may also run your containers side-by-side with totally unrelated containers which don't use much CPU but use lots of RAM or disk, for instance.

All that is to say, yes, your single container can and will handle multiple simultaneous requests, and your program should be aware that this is going on. This isn't usually an issue, but it does mean you should avoid issues that may cause contention such as database locking, or *all* your containers could grind to a screeching halt.

Answer (score 7):

First, please take a look at [docker.io](http://docker.io) and the [tutorial](https://www.docker.com/tryit/) - it's important to have a solid understanding of how this is intended to be used before you get into solving specific architectural problems.

Now, in the PHP world, you would have Apache with mod_php (or nginx / php_fpm, or other) running within your container. That container will serve all incoming requests.

If you need to load-balance your application, then you would have another container (likely on another host) with a reverse proxy (like HAProxy) that would handle this for you. You could also configure your DNS to round-robin between your webserver instances with or without a HAProxy.

Comment: This answer is worth considering along with the accepted one.  The only thing missing is that it doesn't speak to my specific question which inquires as to whether you would want to run multiple instances of the same process on a host.

Comment: Downvoted because it does not answer the question at all (whether the container *should* answer multiple requests), just provides some general info about running PHP in docker containers.

Answer (score 4):

If you think of a container as similar to a process, this will guide your choices appropriately.

Following best-practice advice of "one app to a container", it *will* be a process, albeit one with certain namespaces attached, chroot-ed, in certain control groups.

Comment: Nice! Okay, so the circumstances of the process itself are - practically speaking - immaterial to it's use.  So I would still treat the host that the process runs on as one normally would, and in the case of software that is capable of handling multiple connections, would not attempt to run multiple instances of it.

Comment: Yes; you might have reasons to run multiple instances, e.g. pinning them to different cores for NUMA, but those reasons would be the same with or without Docker.